# Base64 String save only last image taken by camera

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, base64

why Base64 encode only one Byte Array from byte[] ArrayList ?

see my code below:

```
 ArrayList<byte[]> stringImgArry = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

 bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        stringImgArry.add(byteArray);

  Log.d("LOG_TAG", " byteArray  " + byteArray);//[B@73c1473
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", " String_byteArray  " + stringImgArry);//[[B@73c1473, [B@d50868c]

        List<String> encodedImageList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < stringImgArry.size(); i ++) {
            encodedImageList.add(Base64.encodeToString(stringImgArry.get(i), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
             ImgString = String.join("    NEXT IMAGE    ", encodedImageList);
        }

        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Array  base64 image : " + ImgString);
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "encoded Image List  : " + encodedImageList);
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Array  base64 image size  : " + encodedImageList.size());//2
```

and then save ImgString to sqlite like this

```
mDatabase.execSQL(insertSQL, new String[]{date, description, ImgString});
```

and my database looks like this[image: here i the sqlite structure]

please anybody help me to find solution to encode Arraylist of byte array with Base64?
[image: 1st Logcat]
[image: 2nd Logcat]
[image: 3rd Logcat]
[image: 4th Logcat]
[image: 5th Logcat]

Comment: How many times are `stringImgArry.add(byteArray)` called in the code you have provided? Answer: 1. So, how many byte-arrays are there in your `stringImgArry` when you enter the for-loop? Answer: 1. Even if you had more entries in the list, only the last converted entry in the list would be saved to `encodedImage`, all previous conversions overwritten by the next one.

Comment: it depend on how many images i capture. when i capture two images there are two byte-arrays in my `stringImgArry`

Comment: so what i have to do to save all entries ?

Comment: You mean that the middle part of your code is repeated for each image you have captured? Then the main problem is that you are overwriting previous images with the last one. You need to make `encodedImage` a `List` as well and add to it in the for-loop, or join the encoded strings together, like `encodedImage += Base64...`, depending on what you want to do with the encoded strings later.

Comment: can you help me with a sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> encodedImageList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < stringImgArry.size(); i ++) {
  encodedImageList.add(Base64.encodeToString(stringImgArry.get(i), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
```

Now `encodedImageList` contains an encoded string for each image.

If you want this as a single `String` with all of them separeted by a newline you could do

```
String string = String.join("\n", encodedImageList);
```

Or do whatever you want with your list of encoded images.

Comment: This code also gives me only one image. and when i store this string to SqLite it gives me null data

Comment: It's difficult to help when we don't get the whole picture. You should update your question with code showing what happens when you collect the data and what you are trying to do with it after. Without more information I'm not able to provide more help.

Comment: What's the output of the 2 log statements you didn't provide the output from?

Comment: please see my post. i added my full logcat